# Which tags are recommended to wrap <p>?

Tags: html, xhtml, markup, validation

Definitely its wrong to use `<p>` elements because `<p>` can contain only inline elements.. [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) throws an error:

> **document type does not allow element "p" here;...**

Which tags are *recommended* to contain `<p>` element?

In other words, which tags are recommended to contain the block-level elements?

Comment: are you closing your <p> tags? with </p> ?

Comment: @Ollie why? 4 more to go

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity or do you have a specific need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, the elements that can contain `<p>` are:

Those that can have 'Flow' children;

**address, article, aside, blockquote, body, caption, dd, details, dialog, div, dt, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, header, li, menu, nav, section, td, th**

And those that have a 'Transparent' content model, when *their* parents can have 'Flow' children;

**a, audio, canvas, del, ins, map, object, video**

Source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/section-index.html#elements-1, the 'Element' and 'Children' columns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link. I was trying to use `<p>` inside `<p>` and `<div>` inside `<a>` with `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` *DOCTYPE* and the W3 validation was failing. I wonder if `<a>` has *transparent model* in HTML5 and `<a>` is wrapped **inside** a `<div>`, would the validation pass if `<a>` contains `<div>`? Also, is there a concept of transparent model in HTML4 and is `<a>` included in the set?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use `<div>` as much as possible :

```
html > body > div > p > span
```

`<p>` is used for paragraph, then you shouldn't have any block element inside.

An usual problem happens when you've got a wysiwyg editor, where users can add their own `<p>` tags. Then `<div>` is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `<div>` elements would be used, but there could be a more semantic tag to use.If the content is a quotation, you might want to use `<blockquote>`.

If you are using HTML5 there are several more to choose from such as `<header>`, `<section>` and `<article>`.

Comment: Also note that since HTML5 you can also wrap blockelements in an `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html)**, a paragraph's parent may be any element that can contain [flow elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow). Flow elements being:

> [phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing), a, p, hr, pre, ul, ol, dl, div, h1, h2, h3,
>   h4, h5, h6, hgroup, address, blockquote, ins, del  object, map,
>   noscript, section, nav, article, aside, header, footer, video, audio,
>   figure, table, form, fieldset, menu, canvas, or details

Comment: I think you have that wrong - it says the parent of a P tag is "Any element that can **contain** flow elements". The parent cannot be a flow element itself. I know that an A tag cannot contain any block level tags.